# Bloquear botón por 10 segundos antes de volverlo a apretar

Tags: javascript

Mi problema es que tengo una pequeña página en PHP, la cual al darle al `submit` me realiza una acción en phpssh2, la cual manda un comando por ssh a un equipo para mandarlo a reiniciar. Lo que quisiera es que dicho botón no me dejara volverle a dar clic por al menos unos 10 segundos, mi código es éste:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <title>Reiniciar internet</title>

    <!-- Bootstrap -->
    <link href="css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">

    <script src="js/jquery-1.10.1.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>

    <script type="text/javascript">
        $(document).ready(function() {
            $('#reiniciar1').click(function(e) {
                e.preventDefault();

                if(window.confirm('¿Estas seguro?')){
                    window.location.href = 'http://100.250.254.3/release.php';
                }
            });
        });
    </script>

    <script type="text/javascript">
        $(document).ready(function() {
            $('#reiniciar2').click(function(e) {
                e.preventDefault();

                if(window.confirm('¿Estas seguro q deseas renovar el DHCP?')){
                    window.location.href = 'http://192.168.16.204/renew.php';
                }
            });
        });
    </script>

    <script type="text/javascript" src="../js/jquery.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        $(document).ready(function() {
            setTimeout(function() {
            $(".content").fadeOut(1500);
            },3000);
        });
    </script>
</head>
<body>
<div class="text-center" style="position: fixed; width: 100%;top: 47%;left: 0;">
    <?php if( isset( $_GET['msg'] ) && $_GET['msg'] == 1 ): ?>
        <div class="alert alert-success content">
            El internet fue reiniciado con exito, espere unos minutos e intente revisar el login de nuevo.
        </div>
    <a id="reiniciar1" href="#" class="btn btn-warning">Reiniciar Conexion</a>


    <?php elseif( isset( $_GET['msg'] ) && $_GET['msg'] == 2 ): ?>
        <div class="alert alert-danger content">
            Usted no tiene acceso a ese contenido.
        </div>
    <a id="reiniciar1" href="#" class="btn btn-warning">Reiniciar Conexion</a>


    <?php else: ?>
        <a id="reiniciar1" href="#" class="btn btn-warning">Reiniciar Conexion</a>

    <?php endif; ?>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Desactiva el botón cuando lo pulses la primera vez y luego usa un setTimeOut para volver a activarlo pasado ese tiempo.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Podrías agregar un evento a tu botón para detectar cada vez que se de clic en el mismo. Este evento sería el que llamase a una función para bloquear el botón en caso de que se diera clic sobre él.

Posteriormente, podrías agregar un timeout para bloquearlo durante unos segundos, en este caso 10.

Te dejo un ejemplo de como funcionaría:

```js
var boton = document.getElementById('boton');
boton.addEventListener("click", bloquea, false); 

function bloquea(){
  if(boton.disabled == false){
     boton.disabled = true;
     
     setTimeout(function(){
        boton.disabled = false;
    }, 10000)
  }
}
```

```html
<button id="boton">Dale clic</button>
```

Comment: y ese me permitiria agregarle la funcion submit o sea que cuando se le de clic el me haga la funcion reiniciar1 del codigo q puse mas arriba <script type="text/javascript">
        $(document).ready(function() {
            $('#reiniciar1').click(function(e) {
                e.preventDefault();

                if(window.confirm('¿Estas seguro?')){
                    window.location.href = 'http://100.250.254.3/release.php';
                }
            });
        });
    </script>

Comment: o sea ese codigo que me pusiste que me funcionara con el de la funcion #reiniciar1

Comment: @PedroRafaelSantiesteban Sí, tu dentro de la función bloquea podrías añadir el código que quisieras antes de agregar el `setTimeOut`. Si tienes cualquier problema no dudes en preguntar.

Comment: si mira pero es q cuando el hace la funcion <script type="text/javascript">
        $(document).ready(function() {
            $('#reiniciar1').click(function(e) {
                e.preventDefault();

                if(window.confirm('¿Estas seguro?')){
                    window.location.href = 'http://100.250.254.3/release.php';
                }
            });
        });  ahi entonces me abre la otra pagina y el boton se vuelve a activar